# Getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined"

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Below attach folder directory, server.js and api.js file. Program is not running, give me error like:

```
ReferenceError: dbo is not defined
    at C:\shivapp\mean_app\mandiapp\server\api.js:18:1
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\shivapp\mean_app\mandiapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\shivapp\mean_app\mandiapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\shivapp\mean_app\mandiapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\shivapp\mean_app\mandiapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\shivapp\mean_app\mandiapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\shivapp\mean_app\mandiapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\shivapp\mean_app\mandiapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\shivapp\mean_app\mandiapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\shivapp\mean_app\mandiapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12).
```

Folder directory

[image]

**File-> server.js**

```
var express=require('express');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var path=require('path');
var http = require('http');
var app=express();


var api= require('./server/api');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'dist')));

app.use('/',api);
//8376884527
app.get('*'),(req,res) => {

    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'dist/index.html'));
}   




var port= process.env.port || '3000';

app.set('port',port);

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port,()=>console.log('server running...'));
```

**file -> api.js**

```
 var express = require('express');
 var router = express.Router(); 



var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

var dbo;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mandiapp", function(err, db) {
  if(err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("mandiapp");
});

router.get('/users', function(req, res) {

dbo.collection("user").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(result);
    //dbo.close();
  })
})

router.get('/recent', function(req, res) {
  var collection = db.get().collection('comments')

  collection.find().sort({'date': -1}).limit(100).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    res.render('comments', {comments: docs})
  })
})



module.exports = router
```

Comment: Avoid 'please help', 'plz help' or 'urgent' in your text title or question. A well formatted question + tags should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is because variable `dbo` is not defined, as error suggests.

Your issue is the following code:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mandiapp", function(err, db) {
  if(err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("mandiapp");
});
```

You have defined variable `dbo` inside a callback function which will not be available outside of this scope. You should define it else where and assign to it here.

See below for fix if unclear.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router(); 


var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var dbo = undefined;


MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mandiapp", function(err, db) {
  if(err) throw err;
    dbo = db.db("mandiapp");
});

router.get('/users', function(req, res) {

dbo.collection("user").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(result);
    //dbo.close();
  })
})

router.get('/recent', function(req, res) {
  var collection = db.get().collection('comments')

  collection.find().sort({'date': -1}).limit(100).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    res.render('comments', {comments: docs})
  })
})



module.exports = router
```

You have more undefiend variables which you will be looking for later on in your code such as `collection` and `db` in your `/recent` get handler.

Comment: now .i am getting this error like...TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined

Comment: That's because you have the same issue as the one you just fixed, see the last line on the answer.

Comment: please give me right answer.....can u help me make different file for database connection..

Comment: I gave you the right answer, you should try and fix it yourself. I fixed one for you, rest are the same fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [link](http://doduck.com/node-js-mongodb-hello-world-example/)

remove line : **var dbo = db.db("mandiapp")**;

```
var db = MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mandiapp', function(err, db) {
    if(err)
        throw err;
    console.log("connected to the mongoDB !");
});

db.collection("user").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(result);
    //dbo.close();
  })
})
```